# How to use ajax to update mysql db when checkbox condition is changed?

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, cakephp

I have a table of articles that displays in rows on client side. Each articles has a unique id and contains a checkbox to indicate if this article is checked as a favorite. If it is a favorite, then the checkbox is already checked. If not, it is unchecked. Now I need either js or jquery and ajax to update the table in the DB if and when the checkbox condition changes specific to each row. Another challenge is that I am working in cakePHP MVC environment.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function checkbox_click (id, favorite)
    {
        // see if checkbox is checked
        if(favorite==1)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'check_favorite.php', // this external php file isn't connecting to mysql db
                data:'id= ' + id + '&amp;favorite=1',
            });
        }// if
        // the checkbox was unchecked
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'check_favorite.php', // this external php file isn't connecting to mysql db
                data:'id= ' + id + '&amp;favorite=0',
            });
        }//else
    }
</script>
```

--html-- this is within a foreach loop.

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' id='$rowid;' name='favorite' checked='checked' onclick='checkbox_click('id','favorite',this();' />";


else
echo "<input type='checkbox' id='$rowid;' name='favorite'  onclick='checkbox_click('id','favorite',this.checked);' />";
```

--php file called by ajax--

```
<?php
//Database Variables - with the variables entered it doesn't connect
$dbhost = 'localhost';   // usually localhost
$dbuser = 'username';      // database username
$dbpass = 'password';      // database password

//Establish connection to MySQL database

$con = @mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if (!$con)
die('Unable to connect.' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db('devcake', $con);

// Get the variables.
$query = "UPDATE mytable SET favorite=".$_POST['favorite'] . "
WHERE id=".$_POST['id'] . ";";

mysql_query($query);
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working here? Also, when pasting in code, please try and format and place in a code block, or else it becomes totally illegible.

Comment: There isn't a shred of CakePHP here, you need to read up on it and ajax a bit more at book.cakephp.org

Comment: There is no cakePHP in this currently because when I add it to the controller helpers array, it ruins pagination...then I tried to connect to mysql db the other way. instead of ajax url going to an external php page, does it need to go the controller?

Answer (score 5):

This is the code i use (thanks to samuel)

```
 $('input[name=favorite]').live("click",function(){
    var id    = $(this).attr('id');

    if($(this).attr('checked')) {
        var favorite = 1;
    } else {
        var favorite = 0;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'favorites.php',
        data:'id= ' + id + '&favorite='+favorite
    });
    //console.log('id: ' + id + ' Publico: '+publico + 'Value: '+value);

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a doozy!

First, let's sharpen up the html. Checkboxes, by default, send the value 'on' when checked (unless you have specified `value` in the input tag, which you have not). Go ahead and remove the onClick event entirely, as we'll be doing it with jQuery to simplify things and better separate your behavior from your presentation.

Second, let's get your php file setup properly. If you haven't actually modified the username and password, it's likely that their values should actually be

```
$dbhost='localhost';
$dbuser='root';
$dbpass='';
```

Once that connection is working, we need to fix the way we're dealing with the posted data. The way I like to do it is to pull it out into separate variables so that, should something go wrong, I can just do a `print variable;` and see what value (if any) it has.

A better way to get the posted data inside your php file, and query it, would be the following:

```
$id=$_POST['id'];
$favorite=$_POST['favorite'];
$query="UPDATE mytable SET favorite='$favorite' WHERE id='$id'";
```

What this does is changes the value of the favorite column to either 'on' or ''. So, turn to where you actually output the checkboxes and insert some php to check the box if it is checked already in the database. Like so.

```
 echo "<input type='checkbox' id='$rowid;' name='favorite'";
if(//check in database if 'favorite' column is set to 'on'){
print "checked='checked'";
 }
    echo "/>";
```

Note the lack of an onClick event. We'll handle that with jquery.

```
    $('input[name=favorite]').click(function(){
    //if a checkbox with name 'favorite' is clicked, do the following.
    //grab the id from the clicked box
    var id=$(this).attr('id');
    //grab the value from the checkbox (remember, if it is checked it will be 'on', else ''
    var favorite=$(this).val();
    //setup the ajax call
    $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'check_favorite.php',
            data:'id= ' + id + '&favorite='+favorite
        });
    }
    });
```

THERE. Whew. I think that ought to take care of some of it, if not the lot of it.

Comment: Why 'on'? I need the value to write to db as either 1 or 0.

Comment: @samuel..is there some syntax missing? I noticed that <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){     was missing but I still can't seem to get a response on click. I also tried to pr $favorite but nothing appeared...wanted to see if it was printing a 1 or 0 or on or "

Comment: The default value a checkbox sends, when checked, is 'on.' If you want to change it when it goes into the database you can do a logic check with if(checkbox='on), checkbox='1', else checkbox='0' (pseudo code :P)
if you can't tell where things are breaking in your javascript, try throwing a few  `alert('GOT HERE');` pieces in there. I usually do it to find out where my logic is breaking, or where it is even getting to.
Does this explain?

Comment: Just a though, is this going to work if the checkbox is checked by clicking on the <label>?

Comment: I have not checked. Though for his purposes I think it was just a standalone box, in a column. I'll check into it, as it'd be good to know later on.

Answer (score 0):

Change your echo statements to the following and try it out and let me know how that goes:

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' id='$rowid;' name='favorite' checked='checked' onclick='checkbox_click('$rowid','favorite',this();' />";

else
echo "<input type='checkbox' id='$rowid;' name='favorite'  onclick='checkbox_click('$rowid','favorite',this.checked);' />";
```

Comment: In PHP, if you want to check if the checkbox was ticked, you can do:   echo ( isset($_POST['favorite']) ) ? 'yes' : 'no'; Just change yes and no to your desired values.