# Update mysql database instantly when checkbox clicked

Tags: php, mysql

Previously this was my question:

I would like to ask is it possible to "update" the database instantly when I "untick" the checkbox with the corresponding ID by putting the code in the same page?

Hope you guys can understand what I'm trying to say. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

After awhile I've managed to somehow get it worked in someway but problem now is how do I get my ID from the checkbox? I can't think of anything already.

Here's my brief code:

```
if (isset($_POST['product_new'])) {

$id=$_POST['product_id'];

    echo ("<script language='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('Title: ".$id."')
    window.location.href='product_listing.php'
    </script>");


}

<form name="testing" method="POST">

$select=mysql_query("select * from products_list ORDER BY id ASC");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select)){

echo "<table><tr>
<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
    if ($row['new_arrival'] == 'checked')
{ 
echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='".$row['id']."' />
<input type='checkbox' name='product_new' id='".$row['id']."' checked='checked' onclick='document.product_listing.submit();' />";
}
else
{ 
echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='".$row['id']."' />
<input type='checkbox' name='product_new' id='".$row['id']."' onclick='document.product_listing.submit();' />";
}
echo "</tr></table>";

}

</form>
```

I don't know why I keep getting the latest ID in the database instead of getting the one that is selected. Is there anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery + Ajax will do the trick for you.

Tutorial:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax.asp

As soon as a checkbox is clicked, run a function to see the status of the checkbox, checked or unchecked. If checked, run the $.ajax() function which will send the checkbox id to a php page.

Comment: Is there any way besides this?

Comment: I don't think so. Without having to refresh the page, Ajax is the only way to go. Of course you can opt out from using jQuery, but pure javascript Ajax takes a longer route to give the same result.

Comment: I see, ok. I will try that out. Currently am looking at this thread:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418973/how-to-use-ajax-to-update-mysql-db-when-checkbox-condition-is-changed it seems a bit confusing for me